# Remove openjdk-7-jre but apt-get requires to install openjdk-6-jre, etc

Tags: apt, jre

I installed `openjdk-7-jre` and `icedtea-7-plugin` to use webex in FireFox in Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday. Now I don't have to use JRE so I remove it. But the `apt-get` says that it will install `openjdk-6-jre` and a bunch of stuff like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts
  ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  icedtea-7-plugin* openjdk-7-jre* python-renderpm* python-reportlab* python-reportlab-accel*
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless
  openjdk-6-jre-lib
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 5 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 33.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 86.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I don't use JRE anymore so how could I remove JRE7 completely without to install JRE6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more likely to an stupid dependency, so you shall tell apt-get not to install anything while removing JRE7:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm openjdk-6-jre openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib icedtea-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel
```

If I have to guess, some package depends/recommends/suggest `default-java` or a virtual package and this cause that while you try to remove one the other gets installed.

Comment: It works. Thank for your answer. Woah I don't think that there are any kind of dependency like that. I've never ever seen that before.